# Best way to redirect to main operation route in Laravel with a message after performing edit or a delete function

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have a route say /users that gets me a list of users and I use a modal to prompt the user to delete a given record. This calls a delete get route which performs the delete. Now after this I need to reload the user list /users but this time with a message of user successfully deleted.

I am currrently using an optional parameter e.g /users/{fromDelete?} and if the flag is sent I pass a delete message to the view in my controller. The issue with this a refresh to the page shows the message again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally in cases like this, you should flash (save to the session for a single request) a message to the session, and then display that on the index.

A popular library that handles this for you is [laracasts/flash](https://github.com/laracasts/flash)

To use the library, add the blade partial to your layout:

```
@include('flash::message')

@yield('content')
```

And then in your delete controller:

```php
$user->delete();

flash(sprintf('Deleted User %s', $user->name))->success()
```

This will show the flash message as an alert on your index page.

Comment: Thanks, @atymic that's what I wanted